# Azure functions pre-compiled function, HttpRequestMessage not being passed to function

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

I have the following F# function signature and beginning of function

```
let Run(req: HttpRequestMessage, log: TraceWriter) =     
    async {
        log.Info("HttpRequestMessage" + req.ToString())
    ...
```

when I execute my function and print the value of `req` I get

```
HttpRequestMessageMethod: GET, RequestUri: '<null>', Version: 1.1, Content: 
<null>, Headers:{ }
```

Below is my function.json file

```
{
  "scriptFile": "../WonkTonkLib/wonktonkPostLib.dll",
  "entryPoint": "PutUser.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Any idea why I the request message isn't being passed to the function?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure your project is referencing System.Net.Http 4.1.1.0 and not a later version.

The current tools and the runtime are both being updated to address this without that requirement, but in the meantime, making sure you're matching that version should address this issue.

Comment: thanks Fabio, do you know when the next release will be?